# In what generality is the natural map $\operatorname{Hom}_R(L,M)\otimes S\to\operatorname{Hom}_{R\otimes S}(L\otimes S,M\otimes S)$ an isomorphism?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a commutative ring, $R$ and $S$ commutative $k$-algebras.  Let $L$ and $M$ be $R$-modules. Consider the natural map
$$\operatorname{Hom}_R(L,M)\otimes_k S \to \operatorname{Hom}_{R \otimes_k S}(L\otimes_k S, M \otimes_k S).$$

> In what generality is this map an isomorphism?

Note: This question is reposted from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50699/455). The partial answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50699/in-what-generality-is-the-natural-map-textrmhom-rl-m-otimes-s-to-operator/55171#55171) appears to show that it suffices to assume $S$ is free as a $k$-module, and either $S$ is finite over $k$ or $L$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module. It also seems to state that if $S$ is free but not finite over $k$, and $L$ is free but not finite over $R$, and $M$ is "reasonable" (e.g., $M=R$), then the morphism fails to be an isomorphism.  But it is unsatisfying that the entire analysis (for providing both counterexamples and hypotheses) relies on the assumption that $S$ is free over $k$.

**Edit:** The following reduction is suggested by [a-fortiori](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2035): the term on the left is equal to $$\operatorname{Hom}_R(L,M) \otimes_R (R \otimes_k S),$$ and the term on the right is equal to $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R \otimes_k S}(L \otimes_R (R \otimes_k S), M \otimes_R (R \otimes_k S)).$$ Thus, writing $T = R \otimes_k S$, we find that the morphism in question is $$\operatorname{Hom}_R(L, M) \otimes_R T \to \operatorname{Hom}_T(L \otimes_R T, M \otimes_R T).$$ Replacing $T$ by $S$, we see that we have reduced the original question to the case $k = R$, and consequently, $S = R \otimes_k S$. (I found a-fortiori's explanation overly succinct, but I think I've overcompensated.)

Comment: It is true if $L$ is finitely presented as $R$-module (I don't think finitely generated is enough) and $S$ is flat as $R$-module.

Comment: replacing $k$ and $S$ by $R$ and $R\otimes_k S$, respectively, we may assume $k=R$

Comment: Dear Charles, after the reduction to the case $k=R$ suggested by a-fortiori, Proposition 7 in Bourbaki's Algèbre II.5.3 gives some more information. Namely, the canonical morphism in question is a monomorphism if $S$ is projective as an $R$-module, and it is an isomorphism if one of the $R$-modules $S$ and $L$ is projective and finitely generated.

Comment: After reducing to the case suggested by a-fortiori, you can find a proof for Torsten's remark in Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory, on page 52, Theorem 7.11.

Comment: The Bourbaki condition also happens to be the same one used to derive the trace map in general.

Answer (score 3):

Here is just some sanity check:

We may as well work on the local case. Suppose $R=k$ local and $S=R/m$, $m$ is the maximal ideal of $R$. I will also assume $L,M$ finitely generated. Then the LHS is $S^{\mu(Hom_R(L,M))}$ while the RHS is $S^{\mu(L)\mu(M)}$. So if your map is an isomorphism, one must have:

$${\mu(Hom_R(L,M))} = {\mu(L)\mu(M)} \ \ \ (*)$$
Here $\mu(L)$ is the number of generators of $L$. This rarely happens unless $L$ is free. If $L$ is not, even freeness of $M$ is not enough. For example, if $M=R$ and $ann_R(L)$ contains   a non-zerodivisor on $R$ (e.g, if $R$ is a domain and $L$ any torsion module), then the LHS of $(*)$ is $0$, while the RHS is $\mu(L)$.

In summary, together with the comments: if $R\otimes_kS$ is not flat over $R$, then I think $L$ must be projective for this to be true in any reasonable generality. May be your situation is more specific, if so  can you tell us *what you want to be true* ?

EDIT: in fact, the above analysis suggests the following class of counter examples: Let $k=R$, $L = R/(x)$ where $x$ is $R$-regular and $M=R$. Then the LHS of your original map  is $0$, while the RHS is $Hom_S(S/(x), S) \cong 0:_{S} x$. If $x$ is not $S$-regular then the RHS is not $0$.

Comment: I really think that this answer, together with the comments, more or less gives me what I'm looking for--an idea of what (reasonably general) hypotheses make it work ($S$ flat over $k$ and $L$ finitely presented), together with an analysis of why you won't get good results without these hypotheses (in particular, if $S$ is not flat over $k$--a case which has not been addressed until now).

Comment: Incidentally, "$S$ flat over $k$ and $L$ finitely presented" does cover the case that initially inspired the question.